# Object Printing in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, arraylist

I have the list of Arrays of Objects and storing in to the List

```
Object[] data = [12.0, 0.05, 100.0, 3.0, 5.0, a, cat, 3];

List<Object[]> events = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

events.add(data);

System.out.println(events.toString());
```

When I am printing I am getting in this format [[Ljava.lang.Object;@23e028a9] , I tried .toString() and other but neither worked.

Please help me to solve this problem to see the correct form in output.

Comment: You are trying to print the List, you should print the list's contents instead.

Comment: Well basically, calling `toString()` on an `Object[]` *is* going to come up with that. If you want prettier output, I'd suggest creating a list of elements where each element can print more usefully.

Comment: iterate over the List, and print the iterated element. Using an enhanced for loop seems easiest

Comment: for (Object[] event : events) { System.out.println(event.toString()); } Like this ?

Comment: @Stultuske can't I print and see the whole list without going each ?